# Multiple search terms in TwitterAPI package in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

I am searching Tweets using the TwitterAPI package in Python. I am wondering if there is a way to search for multiple terms in the one request. I am currently using commas to separate the terms, but I think it is only calling the last term.

This is the code I currently have (we are doing research on the controversy over tweets about Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez last year), but I think it is only calling for the 'Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez' term.

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
import csv

SEARCH_TERM = ['eScarry','Hill staffer sent me this   pic','AOC','Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez']
```

Comment: This may be because `'Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez'` word is in all the tweets which have other words like `eScarry` etc. First try with  1st 4 words and then see is it just the last word or all the words are taken care!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Twitter's Standard Search `search/tweets`, then you probably are passing `SEARCH_TERMS` as the value of the `q` parameter. That parameter expects a string not an array.

The quick fix to your particular search is this:

```
SEARCH_TERM = 'eScarry "Hill staffer sent me this pic" AOC "Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez"'
```

A couple of things are going on here. First, if you want simply to match one or more words from a list, you would put the words into a string separated space characters. So you could use 'escarry aoc' to get tweets containing "escarry" or "aoc" or both. Strings are case-insensitive. If you intend to match an exact phase, wrap the phrase in double quotes. And, if you want to match tweets that contain more than one words in any order use the `AND` operator in caps. So, `escarry AND aoc' will match tweets that contain both "escarry" and "aoc".

This and more is documented here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators